# Moving text in VSE blurs or lags behind

Tags: video-sequence-editor, text-object, effects

I am a Fashion/DIY YouTuber who has successfully used Blender & Gimp to produce videos for more than two years now.  I am looking to take my video editing to the next level by adding more effects.  However, I am having trouble with simple things like making my transitions appear clean.

For example, I added a png image into the VSE which is the title for the video.  I wanted it to move across the screen, so I made the image Offset start at 0 and move over to 1000 about 11 frames later.  I used to do this using the Transition Effect, but it looks way worse as far as lag.  Here is the link to the video I am talking about. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCJ0eidTFhQ)  It occurs on the text at about the 34 second mark.  Can anyone help with this?

Comment: After viewing the youtube video I do not understand what the problem is.  The text slides over and it seems fine, probably because I do not understand what you imagined in your head and how it is different from what happened with the pixels.

Comment: I'm not the best at explaining it, but my text is kind of getting a ghosting effect.  I can only describe it like the difference between a java/html website and a flash website.  Forgive me if my terms are misused.  I'm just trying to get the motion to appear smoother.

Answer (score 1):

Well thats interesting, you have discovered that animating the strip's "offset" value only produces a linear f-curve.

[image: Animating offset]

But you can change this curve so that the animation speeds up and slows down, instead of proceeding at a fixed rate. It will look more natural.
Change one of your windows to an F-Curve view, like this.
 See how the animation curve is a straight line.

[image: Change Key > Interpolation]

Or you can press the T-Key to get this menu, choose Bezier (or any of the fun ones on the right, 'back' is my favourite).

[image: Change interpolation type]

[image: Move VSE image strip]

Animating the Strip's Offset value will look far more natural now. Did you know that when you animate pretty much every other value in Blender, you will get the bezier curve automatically? Its just this one value doesn't do it like that.

Answer (score 0):

That one's a breeze when performed in the 3D window (like a 3D movie set).

[image] [image]

Basically you create a text object in front of the camera, then animate it from one side to the other for the distance that will suit the background film.  Render that out on a transparency background and use that video in the VSE, or -

Even easier, have the inbuilt "background image" feature play your bkd movie. (set it's opacity to 100%)

When viewed through the camera, that movie will always be centered no matter what direction the cam is pointing.

Adjust the cam to look at the text.  Start the text object's slide from left to right at the appropriate time.

You might find it faster to only use the few seconds needed in the bkd film and render that to a H264 video file with the text sliding across.  Splice it into the original in the VSE later.

Animating the text is very basic and there are heaps of videos and also tutorials in here.  It involves placing two keyframes to move the overlay text or image of the title.

As you've been with Blender for 2 years I assume you're familiar with the basics, which is all that is involved here.  Any questions, leave a comment and I'll edit this answer.